# What does tittle Thread[pool-485-thread-1] means in debug window of eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using eclipse juno and in debug window I am seeing so many threads running and there is entry as

```
Thread [pool-485-thread-1] Running
```

what does this entry explains.
Is it there are 485 threads in a single pool or 485 different pools?
This entry is regularly increasing i.e. it is now Thread [pool-1125-thread-1] Running. Is this a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most likely coming from the DefaultThreadFactory class (shown below). This indicates that you have created 485 pools since the JVM started, and that this this thread is the first thread in the 485th pool.

This doesn't necessarily indicate a serious problem, if these pools are being created and destroyed over a long period of time. However, it is a little odd to keep creating thread pools like like -- perhaps it's worth taking a look at your code and seeing if you can reuse some of the thread pools (this may help the performance of your application).

```
static class DefaultThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
    private static final AtomicInteger poolNumber = new AtomicInteger(1);
    private final ThreadGroup group;
    private final AtomicInteger threadNumber = new AtomicInteger(1);
    private final String namePrefix;

    DefaultThreadFactory() {
        SecurityManager s = System.getSecurityManager();
        group = (s != null) ? s.getThreadGroup() :
                              Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup();
        namePrefix = "pool-" +
                      poolNumber.getAndIncrement() +
                     "-thread-";
    }

    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        Thread t = new Thread(group, r,
                              namePrefix + threadNumber.getAndIncrement(),
                              0);
        if (t.isDaemon())
            t.setDaemon(false);
        if (t.getPriority() != Thread.NORM_PRIORITY)
            t.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);
        return t;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> What does title Thread[pool-485-thread-1] means ...

It means whatever the specific thread pool that created that Thread intends it to mean.  Assuming you know what the threads are doing, you should be able to work out what is creating them ... and then confirm that the "obvious" meaning is the correct one.

> Is this a problem?

On the face of it *looks* like application is repeatedly creating thread pools ... and that most likely means that the thread pools will not be effective in recycling threads.  That won't be good for performance.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like the default name of the thread assigned by the thread factory.
I can only assume you're creating new thread pools instead of new threads.